# cakephp authentication cookie

Tags: flash, cakephp, cookies

i have a flash application connected with a script on a remote server (X) different from the server hosting the website (Y)

the application on server X needs to get some user information so i need to identify the user by what i have in the cookie

remote server X will get those informations from server Y

is there any way i can get the user name or user id from the CAKEPHP cookie var?
the authentication is the one found on cakephp website

[flash]----request---->[server X]----request---->[server Y]----response---->[server Y]...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set session saving in the database. Then pass session id parameter in every request.